# How does Page specific Meta Tag work in Salesforce Community

Tags: customer-community, seo

How do I set up page specific META TAGS in my SF Community?

How do I set the Page specific META tag property for any of your pages?

For me, Meta Tags defined at page doesn't show up in VIEW SOURCE of pages even if they are configured.

I have placed below  open graph meta tags : https://basecamp.kony.com/s/articlelistview

[image: MetaTag at page level]

However, Meta tags placed in Head Markup of the community does appear in VIEW SOURCE.

Am I missing any steps.?

Comment: Please take a moment to **[edit]** this post so it includes the markup as text rather than an image.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. question, I do also have same question.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same question but I could answer a bit to yours.

SalesForce loads via ajax the whole content of the page, which means, your og meta tags aren't there at first. That's why even if you specify meta tags, it won't be understood by twitter, facebook, etc.

I'm still looking for a solution.

I also did this yeah : https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/01/advanced-seo-lightning-communities.html